# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:. . Original error: Error: socket hang up

Tags: android, automation, appium

only launch application , not run further Test it only happening with latest build . test was running successfully on older build. Also in INtelj idea test keep running not end the test also not not executing in reality on real device

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up

Answer (score 0):

Please try to toggle OFF and then toggle ON again the `debugging mode` on your real device.

Also, please grant the permission with checkbox enabled pop up when you run `adb devices` after doing the above step. Please let me know if this resolves your issue.